# Is there a way to import JSON files into R with a graphical interface?

Tags: json, rstudio

No, this is not a question about how to read in JSON files into R. I can read the files into R fine using the code.

However, I instead want to import them via a graphical interface in a similar way as you can import e.g. from csv, Excel etc. by clicking on the "Import dataset" button in the Environment pane.

Is there an add-on for R Studio that allows this or any other way in which I could achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

While there are a number of packages dedicated to the handling of json-formatted data, I am not aware of any addons or native RStudio functionality that would allow you to load the contents of a json data file into the GUI for exploration as you would with a .csv file.